# tcolorbox: designing a definition with \tcbmaketheorem

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to make a `tcolorbox` that says Definition: in the title and that is it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
%  defi enviro                                                                      
\tcbset{
  theorem/.style args = {#1}{%                                                      
    title = {\mbox{#1} :},
  }
}
\tcbmaketheorem{Definition}{Definition}{%                                         
  colframe = gray!black!50,
  fonttitle = \bfseries
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Definition}{Definition}
  Some definition.
\end{Definition}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't want numbering, nor anything special, you can simply use `\newtcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mydef}{title=Definition:}

\begin{document}

\begin{mydef}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mydef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

See if this is what you want to achieve:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem{Definitions}{Definition}%
{colframe=gray!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{Definitions}{This is my definition}{}
  Some definition.
\end{Definitions}
\end{document}
```

### Remarks

1. I changed `colframe=gray!black!50` to `colframe=gray!50!black` ...
2. I used `\newtcbtheorem` instead of `\tcbmaketheorem` because the latter is considered deprecated.

Comment: I don't want my definitions indexed or any optional arguments.

Comment: @dustin I apologize for misunderstanding your question. I thought you wanted something like this, seeing your code.

Comment: It isn't a big deal.  I was just clarifying with my comment.